# Go syscall.Exec running psql - no such file or directory

Tags: go, psql

I am using Go to invoke the `psql` command. When running it I get the error:

```
no such file or directory
```

The command works fine in the terminal, it's only when running from Go do I see this error.

This is my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {

    args := []string{"psql", "--version"}
    fmt.Println(args)

    error := syscall.Exec("psql", args, os.Environ())
    // We don't expect this to ever return; if it does something is really wrong
    panic(error)

}
```

and the output:

```bash
❯ go run main.go
[psql --version]
panic: no such file or directory

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /Users/myuser/development/golang/go_rds/main.go:16 +0xc8
exit status 2
```

I feel I am not understanding the way Go is calling psql.

Comment: I don’t _think_ `syscall.Exec` does `$PATH` lookup. Why wouldn’t you use `exec.Command`?

Comment: I am using `syscall.Exec` so that the Go program exits and passes to the new command. This is what I was recommended as I was using `exec.Command` at first.

Comment: https://gobyexample.com/execing-processes

Comment: @JimB thanks, I simply didn't read the docs. Got it sorted now.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was `Go requires an absolute path to the binary we want to execute`

To fix it I have just added:

```golang
    binary, lookErr := exec.LookPath("psql")
    if lookErr != nil {
        panic(lookErr)
    }
```

And now this executes as expected.